# security code permutations; security methodology

Tags: perl, security, encryption, permutation

I'm writing a Perl email subscription management app, based on a url containing two keycode parameters. At the time of subscription, a script will create two keycodes for each subscriber that are unique in the database (see below for script sample).

The codes will be created using Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex). My understanding of it is that one way to ensure that codes are not duplicated in the database is to create a unique prefix in the raw data to be encoded. (see below, also).

Once a person is subscribed, I then have a database record of a person with two "code" fields, each containing values that are unique in the database. Each value is a string of alphanumeric characters that is 64 characters long, using lower case (only?) a-z and 0-9, e.g:

code1: ae7518b42b0514d69ae4e87d7d9f888ad268f4a398e7b88cbaf1dc2542858ba3

code2: 71723cf0aecd27c6bbf73ec5edfdc6ac912f648683470bd31debb1a4fbe429e8

These codes are sent in newsletter emails as parameters in a subscription management url. Thus, the person doesn't have to log in to manage their subscription; but simply click the url.

My question is:

If a subscriber tried to guess the values of the pair of codes for another person, how many possible combinations would there be to not only guess code1 correctly, but also guess code2? I suppose, like the lottery, a person could get lucky and just guess both; but I want to understand the odds against that, and its impact on security.

If the combo is guessed, the person would gain access to the database; thus, I'm trying to determine the level of security this method provides, compared to a more normal method of a username and 8 character password (which generically speaking could be considered two key codes themselves, but much shorter than the 64 characters above.)

I also welcome any feedback about the overall security of this method. I've noticed that many, many email newsletters seem to use similar keycodes, and don't require logging in to unsubscribe, etc. To, the primary issue (besides ease of use) is that a person should not be able to unsubscribe someone else.

Thanks!

Peter (see below for the code generation snippet)

Note that each ID and email would be unique.
The password is a 'system' password, and would be the same for each person.

### #

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);

$clear = `clear`;
print $clear;

srand;

$id               = 1;
$email            = 'someone@domain.com';
$tag              = ':!:';
$password         = 'z9.4!l3tv+qe.p9@';
$rand_str         = '9' x 15;

$rand_num         = int(rand( $rand_str ));
$time             = time() * $id;

$key_data         = $id . $tag . $password . $rand_num . $time;
$key_code         = sha256_hex($key_data);

$email_data       = $email . $tag . $password . $time . $rand_num;
$email_code       = sha256_hex($email_data);

print qq~

        ID: $id
     EMAIL: $email

  KEY_DATA: $key_data
  KEY_CODE: $key_code

EMAIL_DATA: $email_data
EMAIL_CODE: $email_code

~;

exit;
```

### #

Comment: Minor correction: `sha256_hex` encodes the digest value in **hex**adecimal, so the characters used are 0-9a-f; g-z are not used, as they are not valid hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a lot of complexity to guard against a 3rd party unsubscribing someone. Why not generate a random code for each user, and store it in the database alongside the username? The method you are using creates a long string of digits, but there isn't actually much randomness in it. SHA is a deterministic algorithm that thoroughly scrambles bits, but it doesn't add entropy.

For an N bit truly random number, an attacker will only have a 1/(2^N) chance of guessing it right each time. Even with a small amount of entropy, say, 64 bits, your server should be throttling unsubscribe requests from the attacking IP address long before the attacker gets significant odds of succeeding. They'd have better luck guessing the user's email password, or intercepting the unencrypted email in transit.

That is why the unsubscribe codes are usually short. There's no need for a long code, and a long URL is more likely to be truncated or mistyped.

Comment: Hi Theran, doesn't the use of rand, with 15 "9's", combined with time(), and the other elements in the string, add a reasonable amount of randomness? Thanks...

Comment: @Peter, while the rand() calls do add entropy, ideally about log2(10**15)~=50 bits worth, the resulting hash still only has 50 bits of entropy from rand() despite being 256 bits long. It can be even worse if rand() is simply seeding from the clock, ideally you'd use a secure entropy source like /dev/random. My point is that you can get the same or better security from a short 16 hex digit purely random code than from the complex system of hashes.

Comment: Dear Theran, do you have an example of the best way to generate the short 16 hex digit purely random code? It sounds very interesting. I'm primarily a database progammer, so when I get into mathematical algorithms, my wee brain starts to sizzle and becomes quite overheated :-). Thanks! Peter

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how difficult it would be to "guess" two 256-bit "numbers", getting the one specific person you want to hack, that'd be 2^512:1 against.  If there are, say, 1000 users in the database, and the attacker doesn't care which one s/he gets, that's 2^512:1000 against - not a significant change in likelihood.

However, it's much simpler than that if your attacker is either in control of (hacked in is close enough) one of the mail servers from your machine to the user's machine, or in control of any of the routers along the way, since your email goes out in plain text.  A well-timed hacker who saw the email packet go through would be able to see the URL you've embedded no matter how many bits it is.

As with many security issues, it's a matter of how much effort to put in vs the payoff.  Passwords are nice in that users expect them, so it's not a significant barrier to send out URLs that then need a password to enter.  If your URL were even just one SHA key combined with the password challenge, this would nearly eliminate a man-in-the-middle attack on your emails.  Up to you whether that's worth it.  Cheap, convenient, secure.  Pick one. :-)

More effort would be to gpg-encrypt your email with the client's public key (not your private one).  The obvious downside is that gpg (or pgp) is apparently so little used that average users are unlikely to have it set up.  Again, this would entirely eliminate MITM attacks, and wouldn't need a password, as it basically uses the client-side gpg private key password.

Comment: Hi Tanktalus; although I'm a Perl programmer, my algebra is weak. What number does 2^512 translate out to? (as in xyz million, billion, etc.) I think the public key option is more than the average user can do. In terms of the network sniffing; that is a concern, of course, and a password would help. But then, of course, the subscribers would have to remember what their password is... so there's that whole convenience issue. Thanks for your help! Peter

Comment: @Peter: 2^512 is a Very, Very, Very Large Number. A million is around 2^20. A billion is almost 2^30. 2^512 is roughly 1.34 x 10^154.

Comment: Dear Tanktalus and Dave... So, besides the network sniffing, and besides the fact that my 2 64 character codes would seem to possibly be overkill, would you say that the chances of someone breaking the code are remote? And thus, the security method is reasonable? (Except for the network sniffing issue?) Thanks. Peter

Comment: @peter: yes, guessing the number (and it's still one 512-bit number, even if you've split it over two 256-bit numbers in the same way that having two independent single-digit numbers is basically the same as a single two-digit number) is, for all intents and purposes, impossible, thus it's reasonable.  Not quite as good as SSL, but still reasonable.  I'd still go with a password over SSL if it were critical info (e.g., banking info), but then I also wouldn't want to encourage clicking on links in emails anyway, so it's probably moot.

Answer (score 1):

You've essentially got 1e15 different possible hashes generated for a given user email id (once combined with other information that could be guessed).  You might as well just supply a hex-encoded random number of the same length and require the 'unsubscribe' link to include the email address or user id to be unsubscribed.

I doubt anyone would go to the lengths required to guess a number from 1 to 1e15, especially if you rate limit unsubscribe requests, and send a 'thanks, someone unsubscribed you' email if anyone is unsubscribed, and put a new subsubscription link into that.

A quick way to generate the random string is:

```
 my $hex = join '', map { unpack 'H*', chr(rand(256)) } 1..8;
 print $hex, "\n";

 b4d4bfb26fddf220
```

(This gives you 2^64, or about 2*10^19 combinations.  Or 'plenty' if you rate limit.)

Comment: Hi Alex... the "thanks, someone unsubbed you" is very good idea. I guess I'm trying to find the correct balance between security and convenience. I saw one unsub method that only had the email address as the parameter, so one could just plug in other email addresses to unsbu someone. Ugh... Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I think you can combine their email address or user id as one parameter in the link, and a random string like this as the second.